# How to change the font-size of google maps mapType controller?

Tags: html, css, google-maps

I can change the google maps mapType controller's size, but cannot change the font size. Is it possible to change the font size through html or css?

[image]

HTML:

```
<div #map id="map" style="height:250px;"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#map{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.gm-style-mtc > div:first-child {
  width: 60px;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.gm-style-mtc > div > div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding in the `!important` property?

`!important` property ignores other CSS rules and those have `!important` properties are applied. For example:

```
.gm-style-mtc > div:first-child {
  width: 60px;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 15px !important;
}

.gm-style-mtc > div > div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 15px !important;
}
```

I hope this helps!